# aframe dynamically added element position is wrong

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have a bunch of elements around the camera.

All elements are set to look at camera.

When they are clicked I'm dynamically adding an entity to these entities (a UI button) that I want to appear bottom right.

When the camera is facing a certain direction, this is correct, but the new entity is placed on the wrong side of the object when the camera is facing the other way.

Here is my function

```
const bbox = new three.Box3().setFromObject(this.el.object3D)

this.scale = this.button(this.icons.scale,'scale')
this.scale.setAttribute('position',{x:bbox.max.x/2,y:-bbox.max.y/2,z:0})
},


button:function(iconCode,id){
const button = document.createElement('a-entity')
const geometry = {width : 0.5, height: 0.5}

button.setAttribute('look-at','[camera]')
button.setAttribute('draw',draw)
button.setAttribute('hotspot-admin-handle',icon)
this.el.appendChild(button)

return button
```

How can i make all new buttons appear bottom right of the enttity that is facing the camera?

Comment: Perhaps try setting the position before appending the entity?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that doesn't seem to make any difference. It's still on the wrong side of the entity. I'll probably do a hack, and just move it depending on where the parent is positioned in the scene, but this seems like the wrong approach. I'll also do a live example as @Tomasz has suggested to see if it's something else in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is something to do with the bounding box dimensions. When I used simple values the child entities were positioned as expected. I've hard coded for how, and will have to find another way of calculating position relative to parent size.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is a child of an entity, you can position it relatively to parent entity, for example

```
button.setAttribute("position", "0 0 1");
```

would position your button in front of parent entity, closer to the camera. You can use `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates to position entity in right bottom corner of its parent. **Make sure to set 'z' coordinate to be more than 0, to make sure it's visible in front of parent.**

Comment: Yes I'm already positioning it. this.scale.setAttribute('position',{x:bbox.max.x/2,y:-bbox.max.y/2,z:0}) . This isn't the problem, the problem is that the position changes depending on where the entity is in the scene even tho the entity is always facing the camera

Comment: Can you provide simple live example?

Comment: Will do shortly

Comment: Something like this but the new entity isn't showing yet https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQxjJW

Comment: What this example should do?